# How to make celery work with gevent?

Tags: python, celery, gevent

Following [the example](https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/master/examples/gevent), celery is started with `celery worker -P gevent -A app.celery --loglevel=INFO`

The startup header shows:

```
- ** ---------- .> app:         app:0x10fab2a10
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost:6379/0
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (gevent)
```

Note that the concurrency is set to 4

in `app.py`:

```
import gevent
@celery.task(bind=True)
def add_five_times(self, x, y):
    for i in range(4):
        z = x + y
        print self.request.id
        gevent.sleep(5)
    return x + y
```

Within the same directory as `app.py`, I started `ipython` and kick start 5 tasks

```
from app import add_five_times
tasks = [add_five_times.delay(i, i*2) for i in range(5)]
```

In celery terminal, the log messages are (GUIDs changed for easier readying):

```
Received task: app.add_five_times[id-1]
Received task: app.add_five_times[id-2]
Received task: app.add_five_times[id-3]
Received task: app.add_five_times[id-4]
Received task: app.add_five_times[id-5]
id-1  // from print statement in add_five_times
id-2
id-3
id-4
....
repeatedly logging id-1 to id-4
Task app.add_five_times[id-1] succeeded in 20.021114759s: 0
Task app.add_five_times[id-2] succeeded in 20.015921234s: 3
Task app.add_five_times[id-3] succeeded in 20.020661308s: 6
Task app.add_five_times[id-3] succeeded in 20.016252998s: 6
id-5 // from print statement in add_five_times
id-5
id-5
id-5
Task app.add_five_times[id-5] succeeded in 20.021114759s: 12
```

What I expect is tasks be interleaved between `gevent.sleep`.
What did I miss? What changes need to be made?

- gevent 1.1.2
- celery 3.1.23
- python 2.7.11

Comment: Please try running celery with ```CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER``` set to 0. There is a default of 4 tasks per process consumed from queue by a single worker process. If you set it to 0, your worker will consume all tasks  from queue.

Comment: @dzejdzej while setting `CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER` to zero indeed all the tasks will be received by worker. But still, only 4 tasks is being processed, as limited by the concurrency setting